# Rails 4.2: has_many using condition from belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many

I have three ActiveRecords. 
Order, which has_many OrderItems. Also has a field named status.
OrderItem, which belongs_to an Order and a Script
Script, which has_many OrderItems

I want to set up the has_many in the Script model so that only OrderItems that belong to an Order which has a status of 'paid' are given.

I'm new to rails, and this isn't my codebase so I'm struggling a bit. I've seen other answers use the :include and :conditions keywords, but neither are valid in rails 4.2

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try keeping things a bit pure by ensuring that the models do not get too involved in defining how other models behave.

Start by defining a scope for Order to define what you mean by "paid".

```
def self.has_been_paid
  where(status: "Paid")
end
```

Then you can associate OrderItems with a paid Order.

```
belongs_to :paid_order, -> {merge(Order.has_been_paid)}, :class_name => "Order", :foreign_key => :order_id
```

... and a scope ...

```
def self.for_paid_orders
  joins(:paid_order)
end
```

Then for the Script:

```
has_many :order_items, -> {merge(OrderItem.for_paid_orders)}
```

So now each model takes care of its own business.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to setup a has_many :order_items that only include items that belong to a paid order:

```
class Script < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items, -> {
    includes(:order).where(orders: {status: 'paid'})
  }
end
```